# get array output as key value on doctrine querybuilder

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables for example

student

```
id name

1  John

2  Doe
```

subject

```
id  sub   student
 1  eng    1
 2  maths  1
```

I have a query as follows on student repository

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('stud')
                ->select('stud.name,s.sub')
                ->leftJoin('AppBundle:subject', 's', 'WITH', 's.student = stud.id')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();
```

But I am getting 3 rows with 2 rows as john with different sub and one row as doe.
How could I make it two rows with the sub as an array on the result? I am new to query writing. Hope someone could help

Getting output

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => John
    "sub" => maths
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => John
    "sub" => eng
  ]
 2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => Doe
    "sub" => null
  ]
]
```

Expecting output

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => John
    "sub" => array:2['eng','maths']
  ]
 2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => Doe
    "sub" => null
  ]
]
```

Comment: Please display the structure of the array you get and the structure of the array you need. Simple image is better than many words.

Comment: Do you have mapping info on your entities? It seems you don't, because otherwise you would not need WITH clause and you would get nested array result automatically. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: @ThierryB Updated the question with expected ouput

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT JOIN` returns all records from the left table (here: student), and the matched records from the right table (here: subject). The result is NULL from the right side if there is no match(here: student with id:2).

Here, you should select from **subject**, then `LEFT JOIN` it with **students**. it solves your problem.